# Trechos de código grandes não são exibidos corretamente no app Stack Exchange

Tags: bug

Quando há na publicação trechos de código muito grandes não é feita a exibição correta:

[image]

Isso acontece em todas as perguntas/respostas com muito código.

Comment: Aliás, seria o Meta o melhor lugar para relatar situações sobre o app?

Comment: talvez no metão?

Comment: Metão: [Incomplete rendering of code blocks in Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308822/369699)

Comment: Metão: [Code blocks do not show completely in Android 5 mobile app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281041/369699)

Comment: No iOS exibe tranquilo